# UPS shipping Label Creator using PHP

Tags: php, ups

I have used a shipping label creator code using PHP, however, the image of the label is not coming. I just copy n paste this code from http://webcollage.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/ups-label-print-with-php/ . Please see the code from the URL and suggest. I set this code in my local server (XAMPP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem. At first, I generate the Shipment Digest code from another API (http://webcollage.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/ups-shipping-confirmation-code-in-php/). And paste the Shipment Digest code in the second code ( http://webcollage.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/ups-label-print-with-php/). And the Shipping Label image shown in the browser.